# How to import Render Texture in Raw Image in Unity from Streaming assets using code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, video-player

I have a json file, which contains path to render texture. I need to load texture from that path. What should I use to load from file to render texture and then import it in Raw image?

Little context: I need to use video player in UI. All sources are in StreamingAssets folder.

I use something like this:

```
if(video_player != null)
            {
                video_player.url = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath + data_pattern.Content_Video_Path);
           //     render_texture =  ?;
           //     video_player.targetTexture = ?;
            }
```

"data_pattern" is a data storage class which I use to load information from json.

I tried to use UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture, but it didn't work with render texture.